# Is $x^4-x^4 = 0$ a fourth-degree equation?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

The best definition I could find for the degree of an equation is the following:

> The highest power of the unknown term whose coefficient isn't zero in a given equation

Would

$$x^4-x^4 = 0$$

be an equation of the fourth degree then?

My guess is that it is, as the degree needs to be evaluated from the given form of the equation and not from a simplified version.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No. The degree of the equation is when everything gets simplified into the form $a_n x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_0$.

Comment: where did you find that definition though? the problem here seems that i can't find a formal definition to answer my question

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial - Non-zero coefficient is key.

Comment: Since we're writing polynomials in any form we like, what if the equation is $(x^2 - 1)(x^2 - 4) = 0$? Is that a quadratic equation because the highest power appearing in the given form is $2$?

Answer (score 4):

Equations aren't fourth degree; *polynomials* are fourth degree.  Polynomials are abstract objects you should not confuse with the notation that is used to write them.  There are many ways to write the same polynomial.

$$x^4-x^4$$ is just a way to write the polynomial $$0$$  which is *not* a fourth-degree polynomial.  Similarly $$x^5+x^4-x^5$$ is not a fifth-degree polynomial.

This is similar to how $\frac{6}{30}$ is another way to write $\frac15$.  Many things we say about rational numbers are only true if we understand them this way.  For example:

> A rational number has a terminating decimal expansion if, and only if, its denominator is equal to $2^i5^j$ for some $i$ and $j$.

But then you might ask: what about $\frac6{30}$?  Its decimal expansion terminates: $0.2$. But its denominator is not $2^i5^j$ since it is divisible by $3$.

But no, $\frac6{30}$ is not the rational number, it's only a notation which is one way of writing the rational number $\frac15$, and that rational number has a denominator of $5$.

Comment: so this is the clearest answer I've got, yet there are cases where it's ambiguous. Take this example: is (x + 1)(x -1) the simplest way to write (x^2 - 1) or is it the other way around? In this example is the degree 2 or 1?

Comment: It doesn't matter what is the “simplest” way to write it.  They're both representations of the same polynomial of degree **2**. If you don't know the degree, you can put the polynomial into standard form: $$a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \dots + a_1x+a_0,$$ where $a_n \ne 0$. There is exactly one way to do this for every polynomial. Then the degree of the polynomial  is $n$.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, to find the degree, the numerical coefficients have to be non zero. If none of them are non zero then the degree of the polynomial is $0$.

Now assume that all coefficients are non zero. Then if the polynomial is of a single variable then you can easily tell the degree by seeing the highest power on the variable.

But now suppose that the polynomial consists of many variables. In this case, the degree is determined by finding the term whose powers (of the variables) adds up the most. Then that sum of powers is the degree of the polynomial.

**Edit**

The degree of a constant polynomial is $0$. The exception is the zero polynomial. Its degree is undefined. It's because, let $a,b$ be any two positive integers then $$0\cdot x^a=0\cdot x^b$$

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial#Degree_of_the_zero_polynomial), the degree of the zero polynomial is undefined or negative

Comment: @J.W.Tanner you're right

Comment: So will you edit your answer?